# Upload file to server using WCF

Tags: php, android, wcf, file-upload

I have uploaded a file from my smartphone to server using `PHP`. This PHP side is only for test (because I'm testing that my android app works properly or not...), and there is no problem with client and/or server side.

But my main task is writing this server in `WCF`... I don't know how can I do it.

My PHP codes looks like:

```
<?php
    // Get image string posted from Android App
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    // Get file name posted from Android App
    $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    // Decode Image
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
    // Images will be saved under 'www/imgupload/uplodedimages' folder
    $file = fopen('uploadedimages/'.$filename, 'wb');
    // Create File
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Image upload complete, Please check your php file directory';
?>
```

If you know please help me... *Actually I'm going to be crazy* :(

Any comment and/or answer appreciate.

Thanks a lot.